# how to dynamic call hibernate composite key in drools

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, drools, drools-flow

I am using spring boot with JPA integrating hibernate ORM. In my rule file how to call parameters in multiple entity(used joins).

Please help me. I am starter with drools.

I have the below query :

```
Select vec.memcode,vec.memName from Veclmem vec,VeclmemStates vecst where
 vecst.id.veStatecode=:stCode and vec.veCovcd= vecst.id.veCovcd
```

How to write this query in drool file with dynamic value passing?

The above query have 2-entities and 1- composite class, Veclmem,VeclmemStates and VeclmemStatesId .

veclmemStates entity having VeclmemStatesId entity.

Comment: how would you do it in plain Java?

Comment: I have multiple conditions in my task so according to that build conditions into rule(.drl) file. I need sample of building rule file using above query . Actually i am not understand build conditions using query . Please any possibilities to building rules using my query.  Please suggest me using for that?

Comment: Actually I need, I am giving state code in .jsp <select /> tag ,according that filter some state data using my query. This way how would be get the result using drools?